# Sitecore ChromesTypes ( Dynamic Placeholder ) In WebForm

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, sitecore, placeholder, sitecore7

I have a repeater to generate a dynamic placeholder. In Edit mode when i choose a usercontrol for it, it gives me an error:

> "Uncaught Loaded unexpected element while trying to get rendering html
>   from server. Expecting last tag to be closing script
>   marker16860737917440451880.js:5353
>   Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeTypes.Placeholder.Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeTypes.ChromeType.extend._frameLoaded"

Please help me, tks and best regard

it like this issue: http://developmentsitecore.blogspot.com/search?q=Expecting+last+tag+to+be+closing+script+marker
but i code in web application

this is the ascx file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpAccordion" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpAccordion_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPageHeading" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        <div>
        <p>
             <sc:Placeholder ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Accordion_dynamic_1" runat="server" Key="phMenuAccordion_dynamic_1" />
        </p>
           </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

this is the ascx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item source = GetItem();
        if (source != null && source.GetChildren().Count > 0)
        {
            var filterSource = source.GetChildren().Where(s => s.Version != null && s.Versions.Count > 0).ToList();
            if (filterSource.Count > 0)
            {
                rpAccordion.DataSource = filterSource;
                rpAccordion.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void rpAccordion_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;
            if (currentItem != null && e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var placeHolderAccordion = e.Item.FindControl("Accordion_dynamic_1") as Placeholder;
                if (placeHolderAccordion != null)
                {
                    placeHolderAccordion.ID = "Accordion_dynamic_" + Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);
                    placeHolderAccordion.Key = "Accordion_dynamic_" + Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex, this);
        }
    }
```

And i make these dynamic place holder Editable in place holder setting

Comment: I think we'll need some more information, such as a minimal example of the code you're using.

Comment: it like this issue: http://developmentsitecore.blogspot.com/search?q=Expecting+last+tag+to+be+closing+script+marker
but i code in web application